# how to decode from web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt logs

Tags: web3js, alchemy

I use web3js and createAlchemyWeb3 library.

I receive a transaction event in my log of my Ethereum transaction.

```json
id: 334
jsonrpc: "2.0"
result: {blockHash: "0xe746216f8f73ddd67121bd7a24074e4f56a2bdc5cbe7f783d2673fafd6e992c3",…}
blockHash: "0xe746216f8f73ddd67121bd7a24074e4f56a2bdc5cbe7f783d2673fafd6e992c3"
blockNumber: "0xa7ba59"
contractAddress: null
cumulativeGasUsed: "0x87816d"
effectiveGasPrice: "0x59682f09"
from: "0x72c48277c6d1baae9696e0737b397d2ba2b48953"
gasUsed: "0x1acb3"
logs: {[
 address: "0x002cc07e2a89a7a5807a63fd347fb704b8affb36"
 blockHash: "0xe746216f8f73ddd67121bd7a24074e4f56a2bdc5cbe7f783d2673fafd6e992c3"
 blockNumber: "0xa7ba59"
 data: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008"
 logIndex: "0x14"
 removed: false
 topics: ["0xba02600589e62fdb032edca9214113caeb9517687e7ff5135693b6740e703a13"]
 transactionHash: "0x4928abcc96599d2e4b39e992f26437e3f35d9572e49823847bac61ef7e442dcf"
 transactionIndex: "0xd"
}]
logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000"
status: "0x1"
to: "0x002cc07e2a89a7a5807a63fd347fb704b8affb36"
transactionHash: "0x4928abcc96599d2e4b39e992f26437e3f35d9572e49823847bac61ef7e442dcf"
transactionIndex: "0xd"
type: "0x2"
```

receipt.logs[0].data = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008"

it is {type:event, name:'SignId'} in my solidity

```
{
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "sign_id",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "SignId",
        "type": "event"
    },
```

I use web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters like below code.
but it does not working.
The code stop after compile web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters

```js
const getEthReceipt = async (txHash) => {
  let res;
  const types = [{ type: 'event', name: 'SignId'}];
  do {
    const transaction = await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txHash);
    let decodeParam;
    if (transaction) {
      decodeParam = await web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters(types, transaction.logs[0].data);
      res = parseInt(transaction?.logs[0]?.data).toString(10);
    console.log(decodeParam); // not working
      // await chainMintRequest("eth", decodeParam);
    }
  } while (!res);
};
```

I reffered

[how to decode log event of my transaction log?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87653/how-to-decode-log-event-of-my-transaction-log)
https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/issues/2848

---

I update code

```js
const getEthReceipt = async txHash => {
  // console.log(txHash);
  let res;
  const types = ["uint256"];
  do {
    console.log(1);
    const transaction = await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txHash);
    let decodeParam;
    if (transaction) {
      console.log(transaction);
      decodeParam = await web3.eth.abi.decodeParameter(types, transaction.logs[0].topics[0]);
      console.log(decodeParam);
      res = parseInt(transaction?.logs[0]?.data).toString(10);
      console.log(res);
      // await chainMintRequest("eth", decodeParam);
    }
  } while (!res);
};
```

console.log(decodeParam) and console.log(res) doesn't appear on my console.

The code did not work after web3.eth.abi.decodeParameter and there is no error

Comment: The `types` parameters seems to be wrong, it is expecting an array of basic data types. Try with `types = ['uint256'];`

Comment: Where did you define web3? for example: `web3 = new Web3(...);`